# Div does not display when toggled when styled

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-jsx

Hello so I am trying to make a div appear when an element has been toggled. The function and events definitely work because if I remove the styling then the element appears but when I add it, it has disappeared and I actually have no idea why. It disappears when I add `position:absolute` but even when I  put the height and width to 100% and it doesn't follow. Here is my [Sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-wildflower-lkqek?file=/src/hover.js)

Here is my css:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
#root {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
  background: lightblue;
}
.Main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: abosolute;
}

.Contain {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 998;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Contain p {
  color: white;
}

.Item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px 30px 30px 5px;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0.1%;
  box-shadow: 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.Item p {
  color: black;
}

.Buttons {
  top: 20%;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 998;
  position: absolute;
}



.Overlay {
  background-color: #282c34;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I would post the JSX but they're in different pages and it is probably easier to see the sandbox

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried different `position` values, like `auto` or `relative`?

Comment: I did, unfortunately they made the overlay div not fit the entire viewport which is what I want. If I were to declare my overlay to be visible without being toggled then the styling is fine. it's only If I add the toggle event the styling changes and I have no idea why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that what was causing issues with my style was my `<a.div>` around my overlay component that reduced the styling. So I made the styling for the div to be `position: 'sticky'` and `top:0` and width and height to 100%.

Any children of another div would be styled in relative to fit the parent div so the parent div must be styled accordingly